# Environment variable set but not respected

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I find the following behavior a little confusing, can someone please explain why it happens?

In `/etc/bash.bashrc` I have:

```
EDITOR=vim
```

And it is indeed set:

```
lev@home ~ $ echo $EDITOR
vim
```

I would like `visudo` to respect that. Now, I have read in `man visudo` that it doesn't always respect this variable, but then I don't understand why the following gives different results:

```
$ sudo visudo # opens vi
$ sudo EDITOR=vim visudo # opens vim
```

Note that the `EDITOR` variable must be set for root, too (AFAIU):

```
$ sudo echo $EDITOR
vim
```

Also, when I install packages from `AUR` using `yaourt` (I'm on Arch Linux) and opt to edit the PKGBUILD file, I see:

```
Please add $EDITOR to your environment variables
for example:
export EDITOR="vim" (in ~/.bashrc)
(replace vim with your favorite editor)

==> Edit PKGBUILD with:
```

So the issue is not limited to `visudo`. Why can I see the variable set, but programs can't (unless I specify it again right in the command)?

Technical info:

```
lev@home ~ $ uname -a
Linux home 3.6.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 4 08:04:10 CET 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lev@home ~ $ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.2.39(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set it, but not exported it. Change the line to this:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

Comment: I tried that, ran `source /etc/bash.bashrc`, nothing changed (for `visudo` at least). What is supposed to be the difference? I thought if the files are `source`d, it's the same with and without `export`, am I wrong?

Comment: @LevLevitsky You're mistaken. Exporting a variable makes it part of the shell's environment, and thus, is propagated to children upon `fork()`. Without `export`, that doesn't happen (the variable exists in the shell, but is not propagated to its children).

Comment: That's good to know, but `visudo` still behaves the same way. Is there another reason for that?

Answer (score 4):

After following Chris's answer to export the variable into the environment for child processes to inherent, you need to tell sudo to preserve your current environment. This can be done with sudo's `-E` option which will preserve the entire environment; or in this specific case, add `EDITOR` to the `env_keep` variable in your sudoers file to preserve just that variable.

Comment: How is the `sudo` environment formed? Isn't `/etc/bash.bashrc` read? Why do I see `vim` when I do `sudo echo $EDITOR` then?

Comment: i better way to test is `sudo env | grep EDITOR` then `sudo -E env | grep EDITOR`

Comment: `man sudo | less -p '^COMMAND EXECUTION'` explains what happens better than what i can.

Comment: `sudo -E visudo` opens `vim`. There is indeed no `EDITOR` in `sudo env`... Where does it read it from when I do `sudo echo $EDITOR` then?

Comment: @LevLevitsky `$EDITOR` is expanded by your current shell, using sudo won't change the result.

Comment: @ChrisDown Ah.. So I'm basically doing `sudo echo vim`? Wow, that did not occur to me. Thank you both, you together have made it clearer for me.

Comment: Yeah, with sudo it's easy to end up running parts of your command as root and parts as your own user. This can create some serious confusion.